# Does dispatch_async wait until the previous line is finished before continuing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("setup_cell", NULL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //Line 1
    //Line 2
});
```

Would this wait until line 1 was finished, before calling line 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (in most situations). Objective-C, like C is a top-down language, meaning that generally, a block code that happens above another block of code will execute before it.

The only real way this wouldn't happen is through compiler optimization, but I wouldn't worry about it, as compilers are usually smart enough to keep the code top-down even through all the optimizations they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

Yes: If line 1 and line 2 are just straight forward sequential code.

No:  If line 1 or line 2 are any of the concurrent queue.  For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//
});
```